# Most efficient state management for React and NextJs using Redux

Tags: reactjs, caching, redux, react-redux, next.js

My team is working on developing a new food social-media platform. We have chosen the NextJs framework for the main development due to its server-side rendering features and many more. Our app consists of numerous recipe posts/cards (image, title, and author name).

For now, we are storing all the recipes that are fetched from the server in the redux store as a global cache system: whenever a recipe is fetched, it is sent to the recipe redux state and we just need to pass the ID of the recipe and get the recipe from the cache. This method has allowed us to write less code as we just need to pass the ID to put a like, comment or bookmark on a recipe. The cache is persisted on all the pages of NextJS using next-redux-wrapper and the HYDRATES.

The drawback is that the discovery page contains numerous recipe cards (up to thousands as the user scrolls) and all the recipes are saved in the cache. As the redux state is copied on every page change (that's how next-redux-wrapper works), after a while, the navigation is quite slow.

I'd like to know if there is a better way of managing cache in this case? What do you guys do to cache data in the application? Are there more efficient ways?

Thank you.

Comment: Im quite sure that having copy of state on every page change is not intentional from next-redux-wrapper...?

Comment: I think you are right the doc of redux-next-wrapper says: "The client's state is not persisted across requests"

Comment: I might have expressed myself wrong. Sorry for that. There are some reducer fields that we need on all the pages. Some of the reducer fields are also populated from the server-side so we use HYDRATE for persisting, by conditionally spreading the previous state with the new changes coming from the action (SSR). I don't know if this is the right thing to do or not.

Comment: Is the client reducer copied on every page transition (going from one page to another), or it persists?

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to use [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

To persist only part of your state. Maybe you do not want to save in 1000 recipes of food between pages but only want the most upvoted one. Or maybe you do not want to persist reciepes at all and you want to persist only user preferences. This is why redux-persist can help you to persist only a part of the state

This is mention is the [`next-redux-wrapper` documentation](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper#usage-with-redux-persist)

Comment: Thank you! I am going to discuss it with the team and implement it right away!